# How Spring decide which Base Controller class need to be extend (like MultiActionController, AbstractController etc )

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring 3.0 we use @Controller to inform Spring container to treat bean as controller . 
**Question**  How Spring decide which Base Controller class need to be extend (like MultiActionController, AbstractController etc )?

Answer (score 2):

You're *not* extending a `Controller` base class when you use `@Controller`. Spring uses reflection to inspect the methods on a class annotated with `@Controller` and wire them up.